# hospedar wcf no IIS sem domínio

Tags: iis, wcf

Preciso de um dominio registrado para poder consumir um WCF no IIS de um servidor? Não posso utilizar apenas o IP do servidor?

Comment: Qual o erro obtido? Em qualquer lugar que puder usar um domínio, poderá usar o ip diretamente (desde que configurado corretamente). Porém recomendaria usar o [noip](http://www.noip.com/free) para esta finalidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, você pode apenas usar um IP para consumir um serviço em WCF no IIS, domínios nada mais são que uma forma amigável se se chegar até o IP por meios de redirecionamentos, então, tudo  o que você pode acessar por um domínio você também pode por IP, é claro desde que não exista nenhum bloqueio.